# Странное начисление баллов

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка

Сижу пишу ответ на вопрос, в уведомлениях появляется +10 за какой-то из вопросов. Все данные в тулбаре обновились. Я опубликовал ответ, и в тулбаре кол-во баллов уменьшилось на -10. Зашел проверить в своем дашборде в вкладку репутации, и там стоит цифра 0 - `В этот день не было суммарного изменения репутации` не могу понять что за прикол такой. Меня конечно не особо бомбит из-за 10 баллов, просто может кто-то знает почему такое происходит, и есть ли здесь какое-то влияние с моей стороны :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Кто-то проголосовал за один из ваших вопросов, но передумал и несколько минут спустя отозвал свой голос. Голосование удалено и не отображается в истории вашей репутации.

Смотрите [эту ссылку](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139615/295232):

> **Reversal events from the same day.** When you receive an upvote and a subsequent unupvote event (or an accept and an unaccept, or a downvote and an undownvote) from the same user on the same day, the events collapse into each other and are not displayed in your reputation history.